# Error when installing the pyqt5 package into docker image (Host: mac os m1)

Tags: docker, pyqt5, dockerfile

I am currently trying to build a docker image on my `macOS Monterey 12.6`. When I am trying to install the PyQt5 package in my docker image I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
> Here is the full error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH4Mu.png

**Can someone please tell me why this is happening or how can I solve this?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Preparing work environment
ADD server.py .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
# Preparing work environment

RUN pip3 install PyQt5 # The error occurred in this line
```

Comment: You need to `apt-get install qt5-qmake` (probably in the same line as your existing `RUN apt-get update`).  Note that running GUI applications in Docker containers is challenging at best, and this application might be better run in a non-Docker Python virtual environment.

Comment: ------
Dockerfile:24
--------------------
  22 |     
  23 |     # Install PyQt5 and dependencies using pip
  24 | >>> RUN pip install PyQt5
  25 |     
  26 |     # Set the working directory inside the container
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install PyQt5" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1